# Prismv4: Microsoft supports it or is it their solution?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I noticed that one of my feed items was talking about Prismv4, so I went and downloaded it. But, I thought Microsoft was working on their own MVVM Framework.

So I guess my question is:

- Is this the framework MS is backing/supporting now?
- Is it the same Prism we're used to?

Basically, I wanted to get a framework that's great for WPF and easy, so I was gonna try MVVM Foundation since Prism seemed to be a bit much for me at the moment, who knows... maybe I'll give Prism a chance if MS is backing it.

I know there is another post about the differences in the different MVVM Frameworks, however MS putting a download to one of them is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft is backing Prism.

See this [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx) article, this [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx) page and this [Developers Guide to Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx).